# How to remove everything after a character in a string

Tags: elixir

I am getting a variable that holds a string. I want to trim it to first "?" sign, so I can pass it futher.

For example, I want to always transfrom `x = /example?idontwantthis` to `x = /example?`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I’d go with [`String.split/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3)

```elixir
"/example?idontwantthis" |> String.split("?") |> hd()
#⇒ "/example"
```

Answer (score 4):

If your string always looks like a path + query params, you could also use the URI module to parse it:

```rb
URI.parse("/example?idontwantthis")
#=> %URI{authority: nil, fragment: nil, host: nil, path: "/example", port: nil, query: "idontwantthis", scheme: nil, userinfo: nil}

URI.parse("/example?idontwantthis").path
#=> "/example"
```

There would be a performance trade-off, and splitting the string could be sufficient for your needs, but where your example looks URI-like I'd maybe have reached for this first.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is also based on [`String.split/3`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/String.html#split/3). Uses look-behind in the regex to generate a result that matches the end result that you were asking for.

```elixir
x |> String.split(~r{(?<=\?)}) |> hd()
#⇒ "/example?"
```